# Tips on organizing postman collections?

Tags: postman

We are scaling up to a large micro services build with even more tests to be done via postman (field validations, error tests, etc.)  Curious... How does your team organize your collections of tons of APIs? (by API, by test type, by release, etc) as you pass from team to team?

Answer (score 0):

We create Collection based on API and directories in that collection based on endpoints exposed in that API.

Directories can also be used for different test types and endpoints can be clubbed in that directory. As Postman/Newman gives you the ability to execute a specific directory rather than the full collection, this is really effective for CI, in case you want to execute a particular type of tests for a build.